# How do you pass an argument to a function when you only have its pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Suppose I have two functions

```
void ProcessData(HugeDataStructure &data) { DoSomething(data); }
void ProcessDataInefficiently(HugeDataStructure data) { DoSomething(data); }
```

In my code, I have a pointer to the data

```
HugeDataStructure *p = &SomeValidDataStructure;
```

When I invoke the function

```
ProcessDataInefficiently(*p);
```

I believe I am making a huge copy (of the data structure) onto the stack. On the other hand, when I invoke the function

```
ProcessData(*p);
```

am I still making a copy of the data onto the stack? In other words, is "*p" inducing a copy? Compare this case to the following case

```
*p = AnotherValidDataStructure;
```

Here, I am copying the contents of AnotherValidDataStructure into SomeValidDataStructure, so a copy is, in fact, performed. Does this hold when passing a dereferenced pointer where a reference is required? I'm pretty sure it does not, but can't find documentation to the effect.

Please, let's not get into a "when you should use pointers and when you should use references" discussion. I did not write the methods that I need to invoke, so it's out of my hands. I want to ensure I'm not making huge copies onto the stack when I invoke

```
ProcessData(*p);
```

vs

```
ProcessDataInefficiently(*p);
```

Thanks

Comment: no you're not making copies.

Comment: this isn't C. C doesn't have references

Comment: There are enough correct answers already, but one addition: `ProcessDataInefficiently(*p)` does perform a copy, but that's not because you wrote `*p`.  It's because the class type function parameter `data` needs to be initialized, which means creating a fresh object of that class type, in this case by using a copy constructor.  On the other hand, `ProcessData(*p)` doesn't do that because initializing a reference does not (in most cases) involve creating any object.

Answer (score 0):

No, `ProcessData(*p)` doesn't copy `*p` onto the stack or anywhere else. It's passed directly.

You can add logging to copy/more constructors/assignment operators and see yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The result of dereferencing a pointer is an lvalue. This lvalue binds to the lvalue reference parameter of the function. There is no copy, since copies are (materialized) prvalues, and no part of your function call necessitates an glvalue-to-prvalue conversion.

Comment: with your C++ gold, why not hammering the question with the dupe I provided instead of answering?*

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Because I literally didn't see your dupe post while I was answering the question...